# Merging/Concat non unique multi index with Date

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have 2 data frames as below:

```
df1 =

City       Date           Data1
LA         2020-01-01     20
LA         2020-01-02     30
NY         2020-01-01     50

df2 = 

City       Date           Data2
LA         2020-01-01     2.5
LA         2020-01-02     1
LA         2020-01-03     7
NY         2020-01-01     6.5
```

I want to merge or concat both of them based on 'City' and 'Date', such that the result will be:

```
City       Date           Data1    Data2
LA         2020-01-01     20       2.5
LA         2020-01-02     30       1
NY         2020-01-01     50       6.5
```

What I tried:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index(['Country','Date'],[df1.set_index(['Country','Date'])], axis = 1)
```

And I get error: 
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

I cant do merge either since I have Date as index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is deduplicated pairs by new column created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print (df2)
  City        Date  Data2
0   LA  2020-01-01    2.5
1   LA  2020-01-02    1.0 <- duplicates
2   LA  2020-01-02    7.0 <- duplicates
3   NY  2020-01-01    6.5

df1 = (df1.assign(g = df1.groupby(['City','Date']).cumcount())
          .set_index(['City','Date','g']))
df2 = (df2.assign(g = df2.groupby(['City','Date']).cumcount())
          .set_index(['City','Date','g']))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)
print (df)
                   Data1  Data2
City Date       g              
LA   2020-01-01 0   20.0    2.5
     2020-01-02 0   30.0    1.0
                1    NaN    7.0
NY   2020-01-01 0   50.0    6.5
```

If need remove helper level `g`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1).reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
print (df)
                 Data1  Data2
City Date                    
LA   2020-01-01   20.0    2.5
     2020-01-02   30.0    1.0
     2020-01-02    NaN    7.0
NY   2020-01-01   50.0    6.5
```

EDIT: I think here is necessary convert both columns to DataFrame and then use inner join with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on=['City','Date'])
print (df)
  City       Date  Data1  Data2
0   LA 2020-01-01     20    2.5
1   LA 2020-01-02     30    1.0
2   NY 2020-01-01     50    6.5
```

Comment: hallo jezrael, i think there is a bit of misunderstanding here. As you may see, there is no duplicate in df2. df2 simply has more data (rows) than df1 and i just want to merge/concat those that have same index. thanks.

Comment: @tetehMay - So you need `df = df1.merge(df2, on=['City','Date'])` ?

Comment: yes, i tried it, but python says i must use pd.concat to merge date.

Comment: ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat